# Formating display for a Document/Form library

Tags: document-library, data-view-web-part

I created a SharePoint Forms Library. Every entry is saved as an XML file.

The form contains around 200 columns in the form library. The requirement is, when a user changes any column value in the from the info-path form that value should change color in the document library so that it can be highlighted.

I can change the full row using conditional formatting (SharePoint Designer) but I need to change that value cell or the string color itself.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you must do is to turn on version tracking, see; http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/track-and-view-version-information-for-sharepoint-list-items-HA010209305.aspx

This will allow you to know when something has changed.

The next bit is a bit more difficult, you need to write some client side script, that gets the version information, checks what was changed last, and then highlights it. This may not be possible.

It is easier just to ask the users to select "view versions" if they are interested in what has changed.